# Session Scoping in Laravel Tenancy Package

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant

I am building SaaS Application using stancl/tenancy package, and I am using sub-domains to detect the current tenant used.

My problem is "Shared Session Between Tenants" so I want to prevent that,
and as mentioned in https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/session-scoping/#storing-sessions-in-the-database I should be able to store sessions in tenants databases so it will be private for that tenant, so I made the sessions table and set SESSION_DRIVER=database

but...

Whenever I make a request to any tenant it throws an exception

`` SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'central.sessions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = TdmS0noIZ96njwYvMKIXpejOpZY0heNrIim2o7ib limit 1) ``

Is there a way to force Session to use tenant connection or something ?

Comment: What does `My problem is "Shared Session Between Tenants"` mean?

Comment: If User with id 1 logged in Tenant 1 and switched the domain to Tenant 2 he will be logged in as User 1 in the other tenant

Comment: Just add to users (if users shared) tenancy column - and check in middleware - if user try to get another tenant - throw 403

Comment: Currently Users are shared and that's the solution I did, but I want to move users to tenants and scope them there

Comment: Was this issue every solved? Having the same problem now. @MahmoudBenJabir

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen I dont remember exactly tbh, I remember I added a cookie when the user logs in "tenant_id" and in a middleware I check current_tenant with the tenant in cookies if they are not the same I log out the current user if logged in